# Adding ERC2981 Royalties to an ERC721 Contract

Tags: solidity, nft, erc-721

I just added the `ERC2981` Royalties Contract to my `ERC721` Contract but while doing so noticed there's no way to actually retrieve the Royalty % for any specific Token. The `ERC2981` contract simply doesn't provide us with that sort of ***getter*** function.

To be clear, I'm not talking about getting the Royalty ***AMOUNT*** (in ETH) for a given Token - because that's something you absolutely ***can*** do, by simply calling `ERC2981`'s `royaltyInfo()` function.  I'm talking about grabbing the royalty ***percentage*** (%) that was set for any given token when it was minted (like 5%, or 7.5%, etc.)

So my question then is simply this: can I just ***add*** a getter function to **OpenZeppelin's** `ERC2981` contract? Are we allowed to do that?
Or will that cause that contract to no longer be conformant to the necessary standards of ERC and somehow cause our contract to fail?

(And yes, I can reverse engineer and figure out the % amount if I know the original price and the royalty amount, but the question is more about the ability/permission to edit templated contracts.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add a getter function. That is not prohibited.

Maybe you will be the only person to use that but that's okay.